# Edit Lead Convert Page in SugarCRM CE

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I'm new to SugarCRM but I want to know how to edit the Lead convert page in SugarCRM CE. After creating the Leads there is a button called 'Convert Lead.' When I click it, the Convert Lead page displays but how can I edit the page itself? I want to add different fields to the page. It doesn't seem like you can achieve this in Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Copy.

**modules/Leads/metadata/convertdefs.php**

and save it in the custom directory as:

**custom/modules/Leads/metadata/convertdefs.php**

2) Add the fields you’d like to the corresponding target module’s array within the file.

```
$viewdefs['Contacts']['ConvertLead'] = array(

array(
    'description',
),

// Added below description in order to copy this value from Leads to Contacts module
array(
    'do_not_call' 
),
```

3) Admin -> Repair -> Quick Repair and Rebuild

To add a new panel to covertdefs.php, for instance, Cases.

```
$viewdefs['Cases']['ConvertLead'] = array(
    'copyData' => false,
    'required' => false,
    'templateMeta' => array(
        'form'=>array(
            'hidden'=>array(
                '<input type="hidden" name="opportunity_id" value="{$smarty.request.opportunity_id}">',
                '<input type="hidden" name="case_id" value="{$smarty.request.case_id}">',
                '<input type="hidden" name="bug_id" value="{$smarty.request.bug_id}">',
                '<input type="hidden" name="email_id" value="{$smarty.request.email_id}">',
                '<input type="hidden" name="inbound_email_id" value="{$smarty.request.inbound_email_id}">'
            )
        ),
        'maxColumns' => '2',
        'widths' => array(
            array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30'),
            array('label' => '10', 'field' => '30'),
        ),
    ),
    'panels' =>array (
        'LNK_NEW_CASE' => array (
            array (
                array('name'=>'name', 'displayParams'=>array('size'=>90)),
            ),
            array (
                'status', 'priority'
            ),

            array (
                array('name' => 'description', 'displayParams' => array('rows'=>10, 'cols'=>90) ),
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

Comment: i need to add a new panel in convertdefs.php

Comment: Please see refined answer.

Comment: Does this work for dropdown lists? Because my custom field does not show and its a dropdown field, its an industry_c field using industry_dom. Doesn't output.